# Why are Masstransit setting anycast on consumer queue when using ConsumerEndpointQueueNameFormatter

Tags: masstransit, activemq-artemis

I have recently asked a few Masstransit related questions and maybe this is the last one.

I register my consumers through configuration and it works fine. Masstransit conventions name consumer queues to "Consumer..VirtualTopic. which is good enough. However i realize that if another api want to listen to same Topic and name Consumer identical or using a bad choice of naming the Artemis console view do not say that much about what Api are actually listening.

I'm aware of that proper namning om Consumer class could help Masstransit and Console view here to create good queue names that tell us "who is listening on what topic".

But I would like to use my own custom Formatter and implement IActiveMqConsumerEndpointQueueNameFormatter. It works fine but i noticed that queue are created as Anycast now. Before using the formatter it was created as Multicast.
Can someone please shed light on this behaviour?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Artemis is very particular about queue names. If you're trying to customize them, you have to do it right. Look at the built-in entity and endpoint name formtters and be sure to "customize" it correctly. If your version doesn't work, but MT's does, yours is doing something wrong.